# How to append a sheet to existing Excel file without facing with OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, out-of-memory

I've got an Excel file of one sheet with ~ 150 thousand rows in it.

I used SXSSFWorkbook to create this file, and there're no any problems with it so far.

Now I'm planning to open the file and append a new sheet containing, say, 1 row in it:

```
    final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("file.xlsx"));
    final XSSFWorkbook xssf = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    final SXSSFWorkbook sxssf = new SXSSFWorkbook(xssf);
```

**new XSSFWorkbook(fis)** causes OOM:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   at
>   java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236) ~[na:1.8.0_151]     at
>   java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource$FakeZipEntry.(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:129)
>   ~[poi-ooxml-3.11.jar:3.11]    at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:55)
>   ~[poi-ooxml-3.11.jar:3.11]    at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:88)
>   ~[poi-ooxml-3.11.jar:3.11]    at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:272)
>   ~[poi-ooxml-3.11.jar:3.11]    at
>   org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
>   ~[poi-ooxml-3.11.jar:3.11]    at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:258)
>   ~[poi-ooxml-3.11.jar:3.11]

... and so on.

The question is: how am I supposed to open the file with a view to create a new sheet with some rows in it (not many rows, actually)?

*It's important to note that the heap space is very limited, and there's no opportunity to enlarge it.*

Comment: Your requirement is not possible to solve that general. For appending a sheet the workbook must be opened in memory because of many relations between a sheet and it's  workbook. If that is not possible because of memory restrictions, then appending a sheet to the workbook is not possible. Only possibility would be inserting the new sheet's XML in the Excel file and then creating the relations between the new sheet and the workbook manually step by step. But then one must know exactly the structure of the workbook and the new sheet to know what relations to the workbook must be set.

Comment: @AxelRichter, where can I find out more about creating relations manually?

Comment: To do so one must know how Excel stores the single XML files and their relations in it's `*.xlsx` ZIP archives. Will try giving an example until tomorrow. But why not at least having the basic structure of the Workbook including all sheets from the beginning. And using `SXSSF` only to fill the big amount of data into the existing sheets then?

Comment: Now that I have changed the approach to creating a document, it seems to me that the option of pre-creating the file of the desired structure is the only correct approach in my situation. Thank you, @AxelRichter!

Comment: @AxelRichter, why didn't you post your first comment as an answer?

I may be new here, but it's likely answers are more valuable than comments in terms of reputation.

Comment: For me: "it is not possible" is not a valuable answer. If you found a valuable answer with the help of my comments then do posting that answer here as answer to your own question. Maybe this will help others who have the same problem and maybe you earn reputation from this.